# Typescript does not detect property being changed by method

Tags: typescript

So I have the following code:

```js
class A {
  constructor(private num: number = 1) {

  }

  private changeNum() {
    this.num = Math.random();
  }

  private fn() {
    if(this.num == 1) {
      this.changeNum();
      if(this.num == 0.5) {
        // do stuff
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is a class, which has a property `num` and a function `changeNum` that changes that number.

Then, it also has another function `fn` which firstly checks whether `num` is equal to 1 and if so, changes `num` through `changeNum` and checks it again.

The problem is that Typescript does not detect that num was changed through `changeNum` and throws the following error:

`This condition will always return 'false' since the types '1' and '0.5' have no overlap.`

Is there a way to get Typescript to recognize that `num` was changed through `changeNum`?

EDIT: One thing that I found is that changing `if(this.num == 0.5)` to `if(this.num == Number(0.5))` makes the program compile correctly but that certainly doesn't seem like a good solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a know issue with the control flow analysis.

> The primary question is: When a function is invoked, what should we assume its side effects are?
>
> One option is to be pessimistic and reset all narrowings, assuming that any function might mutate any object it could possibly get its hands on. Another option is to be **optimistic and assume the function doesn't modify any state.** Both of these seem to be bad. (Emphasis added)

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998

TypeScript is taking the optimistic approach and assuming that the function only modifies its own state. That suggests a workaround: do not mutate external state in a function or method. For instance, you could rewrite your demo like this:

```
class A {
  constructor(private num: number = 1) { }

  private getNewNum() {
    return Math.random();
  }

  private fn() {
    if (this.num === 1) {
      this.num = this.getNewNum();
        if (this.num === 0.5) {
          // do stuff
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The upshot of this is that your program will take [a more functional approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Comment: GetNewNum() is not a pure function. It will return different results when called with the same parameters. There was a question about random functions being not pure in stackoverflow.